# openssl_pkey_new() throwing errors -- Proper openssl.cnf setup for php

Tags: php, openssl, private-key

**Okay, It's become clear that this issue is an issue related with the setup of openssl on the Linux server and how to properly setup a custom openssl.cnf file. I am not looking for anything complicated but I need a front-end to be able to create self-signed client certificates for authentication to my webservice. So I need to be able to use my CA to create intermediate CAs for client companies and then allow them a secure interface to issue client certificates for their employees. Logins are based on whether you belong to a specific intermediate CA and that your certificate or the intermediate CA hasn't be revoked.

*For anyone wondering, we can use self-signed certificates because they are only used for our server to authenticate users and since we issued them, we trust them. Also it would be way too expensive for a startup to establish themselves as an intermediate CA through the commercial offerings AFAIK. Microsoft can do that, we can't. Our webserver itself uses a CA signed certificate.*

I know that php code for setting this kind of thing up is straight forward but what isn't is how to properly setup openssl. I have tried several different examples on the net and none of them seem to work for my setup and they all seem to be different. One box was fresh install of Centos 6.2 and I am still getting errors.

Can anyone point me in the proper direction for setting up openssl, apache2 and php so that I can use these php libraries without errors? Our virtual server is using debian squeeze and I have full control of software installed.

Thanks.

**open_pkey_new()** is returning errors such as error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value. Yet I am passing a path to a openssl.cnf file so I don't know why I'm still getting this problem. Here's my relevent code

```
<?php
$cwd=getcwd();
$distname= array(
    "countryName" => "CA",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "Ontario",
    "localityName" => "Toronto",
    "organizationName" => "G4 Apps",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "Development",
    "commonName" => "Mark Lane",
    "emailAddress" => "nobody at gmail.com"
        );
$password = 'seanix';

$cacert_location=$cwd."/certs/CA/g4CA.crt";
$cakey_location=$cwd."/certs/CA/g4CA.key";
$cnf=$cwd.'/certs/myopenssl.cnf';
$configArgs = array(
        'config' =>$cnf
);
?>
```

Here's my function that makes the keys.

```
<?php
function makekey($password,$configArgs) {
    $key= openssl_pkey_new($configArgs);
    //print_r($configArgs);
    openssl_pkey_export($key, $pkeyout,$password);
    if (($e=openssl_error_string()) ==false) return $pkeyout;
    else {
        do {

            echo $e . "<BR>";
        } while($e=openssl_error_string());
        return -1;
    }
}
?>
```

I've tried relative paths too to the configfile and it still won't work. Looks like it might be the host providers ssl setup. I switched to a local virtual machine and I got the key to generate but now I'm getting the same error when creating a csr.

**error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value**

```
<?php
function newcsr($distname,$key,$configArgs) {
    $csr=openssl_csr_new($distname,$key,$configArgs);
    openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrout);
    if (($e=openssl_error_string()) ==false) return $csrout;
    else {
        do {

            echo $e . "<BR>";
        } while($e=openssl_error_string());
        return -1;
    }
}
?>
```

**openssl.conf** This looks to be an error in openssl.cnf so I've included the file.

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

oid_section     = new_oids


[ new_oids ]


tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = g4CA      

####################################################################
[ g4CA ]

dir     = /home/g4apps/secure.g4apps.com/generator/certs    
certs       = $dir/     
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      
database    = $dir/index.txt    


new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     

certificate = $dir/CA/g4CA.crt  
serial      = $dir/serial       
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    

crl     = $dir/CA/g4CA.crl  
private_key = $dir/CA/g4CA.key  
RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    

x509_extensions = usr_cert      

name_opt    = ca_default        
cert_opt    = ca_default        


default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

policy      = policy_match


[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_md      = md5
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

string_mask = utf8only

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = CA
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = ON

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default    = Toronto

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = G4 Apps



organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)

commonName          = Common Name (eg, your name or your server\'s hostname)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = lmlane@gmail.com
emailAddress_max        = 64


[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer



[ v3_req ]


basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = CA:true


[ crl_ext ]

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   

[ tsa_config1 ]

dir             = ./demoCA      
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    
crypto_device   = builtin       
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  

certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem 
default_policy  = tsa_policy1       
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3
digests     = md5, sha1     
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  
clock_precision_digits  = 0 
ordering        = yes   

tsa_name        = yes   
ess_cert_id_chain   = no
```

Stack trace `strace php getkeystore.php &> stack.trace`

http://secure.g4apps.com/generator/stack.trace

Comment: From the error message, it looks like there's a missing or incorrect setting in openssl.cnf

Comment: Is that definitely the full error message? I've seen this before with more after "no value" that indicates the ini group where the error occurs. Have you tried running it from the command line using the same config, and `--verbose` to see if you can get more info out of it? You're positive the path to the config is correct, but have you double checked the permissions, to make sure it can actually be read?

Comment: There is no `--verbose` flag in my version of openssl. I have tried from the command line and it seems to work. Generating a key works and uses the same config. I have already fixed the path for the config file for so that key generation would work so it's not that.

Comment: My mistake it's `-verbose`, I was working from memory. `openssl ca -verbose`. Errors usually have additional information. Like `7491:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:358:
unable to load CA private key`. If it works via the command line, and not from PHP, I'd still lean towards PHP not having permissions to read the config file. Tried the PHP version on the command line too? As the same user where OpenSSL CL works? Maybe strace it to make sure it opens the file?

Comment: Getting closer. PHP is having no problem reading the config file but according to strace the openssl functions are trying to use /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf instead. So there's something wrong with my openssl configuration in php. Leigh if you form an answer, I can award the bounty 10 minutes left.

Comment: The trace also shows a read of `generator/certs/myopenssl.cnf` (which is much shorter than `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`) - I'd probably start by taking a direct copy of the default config, and then only changing the parts I needed to change, instead of building a config from the ground up.

Comment: That's what I did in the first place.

Comment: Interestingly enough I get the same errors use the default openssl.cnf

Comment: The reason myopenssl.cnf is so much smaller than the default is I removed the comments. Other than that I only changed a few values that don't have anything to do with key generation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this on my Mac and a fresh install of CentOS 6.3 and I'm getting the same error. I get my CentOS packages from IUS. It's weird though because even though I'm getting this message, the key is actually being generated.

The following code:

```
$res = openssl_pkey_new();
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey);
var_dump(openssl_error_string());
var_dump($privkey);
```

Gives me the following output:

```
string(68) "error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value"
string(887) "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"
```

I suspect it being a bug in PHP. Some sort of openssl configuration PHP is getting hung up on. I found a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33237&edit=1) about this on php.net, but it "started working" for the user so the bug was closed.

As an alternative, you can check out [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib), a library purely written in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into phpseclib a bit. Might have to use that.

Comment: @Luke This is not a PHP error, this is an OpenSSL error that is relayed back through a PHP wrapper function. You can see how thin the wrapper is [in PHPs openssl.c](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/openssl/openssl.c#4031) and it directly calls [the OpenSSL function (`val = ERR_get_error();`)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ERR_get_error.html)

Comment: I gave up on using openssl so the suggestion to use phpseclib is the better solution.

Comment: Im missing the end tag.

Answer (score 3):

When using openssl_csr_new make sure the first parameter $dn does not contain keys with empty values.

For example, this call to `openssl_csr_new` would trigger the error

`0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value`

```
<?php

$dn = [
    'CN' => 'example.com',
    'ST' => '',
    'C'  => '',
    'O'  => '',
];

openssl_csr_new($dn, $privKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if your openssl.cnf has

```
default_md = md5
```

in it, else add it to the cnf file and try again if that helps.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, don't you agree?

Comment: An answer is a comment that suggests a resolution, don't you agree? :-)

Comment: Yes, but this speculates on a *possible* solution; it doesn't provide solid guidance towards resolving the situation. :-)

Comment: When there can be N number of things that can go wrong, then we can only give *possible* solutions, and not solid guidance

The problem might not just a coding issue, it can be incorrect cnf creation, corrupt OpenSSL installation, PHP SSL support issue or a  plain coding problem among many others..so I don't really see much weightage in what you are saying.

Comment: To give examples: *"Check if..."* is a comment. *"Your code is wrong; here's how you can fix it: ..."* is an answer.

Comment: This is not the problem. The config file had default_md = sha1 and I changed it to md5 but got the same results.

Comment: @Matt: I dont think you get it - or may be you did not read what I wrote in my comments - **this does not necessarily need to be a code problem, so you CANNOT say "Your code is wrong; here's how you can fix it** Did you get that now? or is it still difficult to understand?

Comment: @Matt: What I do understand is that I come to SO to try and help people, and get helped by them. I do not wish to get embroiled in the whole holier-than-thou nitpicking games. Why don't you go elsewhere and try to help someone? or better yet, try helping Codeguy007 (as you can see I am not making any headway here). Anyways, this discussion with you is over for me.

Comment: I help where I can; I was just pointing out that this particular "answer" belongs in the comments section. I wasn't trying to be "holier than thou" so I apologize if you took my comments that way.

Comment: Codeguy007, I am not in my linux box, I cannot try out your code because I do not have OpenSSL in the box I'm using right now. Sorry about that

@Matt: peace out

Comment: ...and once more love wins! Let's hug altogether! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33237) [@Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867760/) mentioned, my conclusion would be:

**openssl_pkey_new() doesn't return a value and therefore is "FALSE"**.

var_dump() just says it returns an OpenSSL key.

**"So it works - "NCONF_get_string:no value" is only some kind of notice."** - [vrana@php.net](https://people.php.net/user.php?username=vrana)

openssl_csr_new() (and maybe more) have a similar behavior.

Comment: "NCONF_get_string:no value" refers to a missing configuration value. See my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this question a dozen times, so time to put in my 2 cents:
An otherwise valid/super complex openssl.cnf can cause up to 10 warnings due to (IMHO) some backwards config parsing done by PHP. After banging my head on the wall I made a shim so that OpenSSL and PHP can coexist peacefully.

**Instead of messing with your openssl.cnf, make your own skeleton cnf and include the default in it, like so:**

```
#PHP shim for an otherwise beautiful openssl.cnf
#Notes:
# duplicate OID definitions fail
# duplicate OID usage generates a warning in most cases
# All duplicate sections/values are overlayed: PHP > shim > include > default
RANDFILE    = /dev/null #PHP warns if this doesn't exist
oid_file    = /dev/null #PHP warns if this doesn't exist
#PHP warns if oid_section isn't in the default section
#PHP warns if oid_section is used in another section (only on initialization)
oid_section = php_oids  #set an empty OID section
.include /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf    #include our working conf
[ req ]
  #included format differs from expected format
  attributes         = php_attr #openssl_csr_new()
  #not set in include
  encrypt_rsa_key    = yes #overriden by encrypt_key
  #uncomment to override include, or if otherwise unset
  #req_extensions     = php_req_extension #overridden by req_extensions
  #x509_extensions    = php_x509_extension #overridden by x509_extensions
  #default_bits       = 4096          #overridden by private_key_bits
  #default_md         = sha512        #overridden by digest_alg
  #string_mask        = utf8only      #overridden by string_mask
  #distinguished_name = php_distinguished_name #openssl_csr_new()
[ php_attr ] #empty attributes section
  #challengePassword = password
  #unstructuredName = i_prefer_structure
  ##NO *_min,*_max,*_default
  ##challengePassword         = A challenge password (6-20 characters)
  ##challengePassword_min     = 6
  ##challengePassword_max     = 20
  ##challengePassword_default = this_wont_work
[ php_oids ] #empty OID section (no duplicates in this section)
  #test_cert = 2.23.140.2.1
  ##NO short_id=long_id,id_num
  ##TEST = test_cert, 2.23.140.2.1
[ php_distinguished_name ] #empty DN section
  #commonName         = Common Name (CN)
  #commonName_min     = 1
  #commonName_max     = 63
  #commonName_default = this_works
  #streetAddress      = this_also_works
  #0.organizationalUnitName = this_actually_works
  #ONLY THE FIRST OID IS USED
  ##1.organizationalUnitName = this_is_silently_discarded
[ php_x509_extension ] #empty x509 extension section
  subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash #at least one value required
  #authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always
  #keyUsage               = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
  #basicConstraints       = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
  #certificatePolicies    = ia5org, test_cert
  #authorityInfoAccess    = @ocsp_ext
  #crlDistributionPoints  = @crl_ext
  #tlsfeature             = status_request_v2
[ php_req_extension ] #empty req extension section
  subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash #at least one value required
  #keyUsage               = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
  #extendedKeyUsage       = critical, clientAuth, emailProtection
  #basicConstraints       = critical, CA:FALSE
  #certificatePolicies    = ia5org, test_cert
  #authorityInfoAccess    = @ocsp_ext
  #crlDistributionPoints  = crl_ext
  #tlsfeature             = status_request_v2
  #nsComment              = "OpenSSL 1.1.1c Generated Client Certificate"
```

Other than the [req] section, feel free to remove all the comments to minify the file.

**Here's corresponding PHP file to test this out:**

```
<?php
  //Serial can't be our desired 20 byte random hex:
  //  [bin2hex(random_bytes(20))] is ideal
  //  [8 bytes] PHP_INT_MAX
  //  file a bug report?
  //NO subjectAltName !!!!!
  //ini_set('openssl.cafile','/etc/ssl/certs/my-ca.crt');
  //ini_set('openssl.capath','/etc/ssl/certs/');
  $pass='password';
  $capass='capass';
  /* it's best to set all of these values in PHP to avoid confusion */
  $config=[
   /*'digest_alg'      =>'sha512',                     /*default_md*/ /*openssl_get_md_methods()*/
   /*'private_key_bits'=>8192,                         /*default_bits*/
   /*'encrypt_key'     =>true,                         /*encrypt_key,encrypt_rsa_key*/
   /*'string_mask'     =>'utf8only',                   /*string_mask - undocumented*/
   'x509_extensions' =>'x509_ext_orig',                /*x509_extensions*/
   'req_extensions'  =>'usr_cert_orig',                /*req_extensions*/
   'private_key_type'  =>OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
   'encrypt_key_cipher'=>OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC,
   'curve_name'        =>'secp384r1',                /*openssl_get_curve_names()*/
   'config'            =>'php-openssl.cnf'           /* export OPENSSL_CONF=php-openssl.cnf */
  ];
  /* all values here OVERWRITE any default DN value */
  $dn=[
   /*'name'=>'', //FAILS- NO EMPTY VALUES*/
   'OU'=>'override_original_OU',
   'surname'=>'new_surname'
  ];
  /* all values here ADD to the default. this array can be multi-dimensional */
  $csrargs=[
   'surname'=>'additional_surname',
   'OU'=>['second_OU','third_OU']
  ];
  $pkargs=[
   /*'extracerts'=>'',*/
   'friendly_name'=>'php-cert'
  ];
  while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_init- {$err}\n");
  if($pkey=openssl_pkey_new($config)){ /* create a new private key */
    while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_pkey_new- {$err}\n");
    $csr=openssl_csr_new($dn,$pkey,$config,$csrargs); /* generate a csr */
    while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_csr_new- {$err}\n");
    print_r(openssl_csr_get_subject($csr,true)); /* show the dn */
    /* sign our CSR using the largest random serial we can */
    $x509=openssl_csr_sign($csr,'file:///etc/ssl/certs/int-ca.crt',['file:///etc/ssl/private/int-ca.key',$capass],30,$config,random_int(72057594037927936,PHP_INT_MAX));
    while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_csr_sign- {$err}\n");
    if($x509!==false){
      openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file($x509 ,'/tmp/phpcert.pfx',$pkey,$pass,$pkargs); /* export the keypair as pfx */
      while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file- {$err}\n");
      openssl_pkey_export_to_file($pkey,'/tmp/phpcert.key',$pass,$config); /* export the private key */
      while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_pkey_export_to_file- {$err}\n");
      openssl_pkey_free($pkey); /* free memory */
      openssl_x509_export_to_file($x509,'/tmp/phpcert.crt',true); /* export the signed certificate */
      openssl_x509_free($x509); /* free memory */
      while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_x509_export_to_file- {$err}\n");
  }else{
    while($err=openssl_error_string()) echo("openssl_pkey_new- {$err}\n");
  }
?>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration (FreeBSD, libressl 2.8, php built from ports) in the section [ req ] the entry "default_bits" was commented out.

By enabling this configuration entry this issue was resolved.