# openssl_seal fails error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value

Tags: php-openssl

I am trying to seal/open a file. Encryption fails and the following error is generated.

```
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

Here's a code sample that can reproduce the issue

```
    // Generate key pair and keep them safe...
    $key = openssl_pkey_new([
        'private_key_bits' => 4096,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
        'curve_name' => 'prime256v1',
    ]);

    $privKey = null;
    openssl_pkey_export($key, $privKey);
    $pubKeyDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($key);
    $pubKey = $pubKeyDetails['key'];
    openssl_free_key($key);

    // Load the pubkey to encrypt
    $key = openssl_pkey_get_public($pubKey);
    $data = file_get_contents('of-some-pretty-large-file');


    // ----- This here fails -----
    if (openssl_seal($data, $sealed, $eKeys, [$key]) === false) {
        echo "Encryption failed\n";
        echo openssl_error_string() . "\n";
        exit;
    }
    openssl_free_key($key);

    $key = openssl_pkey_get_private($privKey);
    if (openssl_open($sealed, $decryptedData, $eKeys[0], $key)) {
        echo ($decryptedData === $data ? "Matched\n" : "Trash\n");
    }
    openssl_free_key($key);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
```

is not caused by `openssl_seal`, but by `openssl_pkey_new`. This does not affect the functionality, i.e. the key is generated successfully, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518810) and [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33237). This also applies to the posted code, which generates a private EC key in SEC1 format and a public key in X.509 format.

The PHP method `openssl_seal` is based on the OpenSSL functions `EVP_SealInit`, `EVP_SealUpdate` and `EVP_SealFinal`, [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c). In the [corresponding](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_SealInit.html) OpenSSL documentation the following is described in the *Notes*-section:

> The public key must be RSA because it is the only OpenSSL public key algorithm that supports key transport.

This means that `openssl_seal` only works with RSA or an RSA key. If the following is used in the posted code:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_new([
    'private_key_bits' => 4096,
    'private_key_type' =>  OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
]);
```

decryption and encryption work as expected.